# Error when adding SSL array inside connection string in PHP PDO

Tags: mysql, php, ssl, openssl, pdo

I need to establish an SSL connection between MySQL server and PHP web application.

Currently we are working with offline server (wampserver) and we need to establish an SSL connection. Th moment I changed the connection script from:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");
```

To:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass, array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    =>'/etc/mysql/ssl/client-key.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT=>'/etc/mysql/ssl/client-cert.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA    =>'/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem'
    ));
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");
```

an error appeared on the login page saying:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away' in C:\wamp64\www\

**EDIT**

I run this query:

```
show variables like '%ssl%'
```

And got the following result:

[image]

Comment: Does you MySQLd accept SSL connections?

Comment: See the edit at the end of my question. I added it right now

Comment: Enabling SSL on the server side seems to be a good start then.

Comment: Any step by step guide ?

Comment: recommending guides or tutorials is off topic for this site. I'm sure google will provide you everything you need.

Comment: Just another question. If I used SSL connections, can I use `AES_encrypt()` on MySQL side, or it is better to use encryption in PHP